# Meetup integration in iphone

Tags: objective-c, iphone, xcode, meetup

I am new in iphone. Please tell me is there any way to integrate Meetup in iphone?
if yes can you give some samples or link related to?

Comment: Meetup is the largest network of local groups. Meetup makes it easy for anyone to organize a local group or find one of the thousands already meeting up face-to-face. Just like Facebook integration i need the integration of Meetup in iphone

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use their API: http://www.meetup.com/meetup_api/